# (javascript) Failed to parse nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently learning about JSON and got stuck to get nested data.
I want to get "id" and "city".

Here's my code:

```
var url = "jsonURL";
$.getJSON (url, function(b) {
    for (var i = 0; i < b.friends.data.length; i++) {
    var data = b.friends.data[i];
       if (data.id == undefined) {
            html+= "<td id='id'> - </td>";
        }
        else {
            html+= "<td id='id'>" + data.id + "</td>";
        }
        if (data.location.location.city == undefined) {
            html+= "<td id='city'> - </td>";
        }
        else {
            html+= "<td id='city'>" + data.location.location.city + "</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

And JSON looks like this.

```
    {
       "friends": {
          "data": [
             {
                "id": "friend1",
                "location": {
                   "location": {
                      "city": "Tangerang",
                      "country": "Indonesia"
                   },
                   "id": "1"
                }
             },
             {
                "id": "friend2",
                "location": {
                   "location": {
                      "city": "Makassar",
                      "country": "Indonesia"
                   },
                   "id": "2"
                }
             }
          ],
       },
       "id": "myID"
    }
```

The problem: total data for "id" is about 600.
If i do *not* try to get "city", the looping seems fine.
And if i *do*, the looping for "id" only showing 4 data.
The result is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

---

## **Fixed**

I change it into
`data.location == undefined || data.location.location == undefined || data.location.location.city == undefined`

Comment: The code you've shown worked for me to process the data shown: https://jsfiddle.net/d2mL7stp/. (As an aside, the code inside your function isn't dealing with JSON: the `$.getJSON()` method parses the JSON to create a (nested) object, and passes that object to your function in the `b` argument.)

Comment: The looping is only showing 4 data when the total data is about 600. And when i delete the "city", everything goes to normal.

Comment: So are you saying the part that doesn't work is in JSON *not* shown in the question?

Comment: there is no "nested JSON" - such a thing is plausible, but rarely usable

Comment: probably somewhere there is an element of the `data` array that has a `location` property that does not have a `location` property within it

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry i don't know the proper name for this case, so i call it nested :)

Comment: @nnnnnn my bad. I've edited the question :)

Comment: no need to apologise - I made the comment to clarify, not have a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Uncaught means the error was not caught in a catch statement, and `TypeError` is the error's name.

Seems like you are trying to access the property 'location' of the undefined object. Test that `data.location` are defined before executing the `if` statements to get the `city`.

**It always work :**

```
try{
    if (data.location.location.city == undefined) {
        html+= "<td id='city'> - </td>";
    } else {
        html+= "<td id='city'>" + data.location.location.city + "</td>";
    }
}catch(e){
    if(e){
    // If fails, Do something else
    }
}
```